# Missing Example from Repo?

Tags: android, arcore

I was going through some of the AR Core content..and noticed specifically this example:
https://youtu.be/ttdPqly4OF8

Is that example available anywhere? Would love to see how they created that drawer (right word for that component?) and how they made the components adjustable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By drawer, I am guessing you mean the 3D objets and models - the creation of the 3D models is not part of ARCore itself. There are a number of approaches but most use some sort of modelling tool and it is quite a skilled and time consuming process to do it correctly.

An example screenshot from such a tools is below - a more detailed video. walkthrough is available (at this time...) here: https://youtu.be/t68hb1alb7g.

[image]

For Animation within ArCore Sceneform, this is supported and documented in the online Scenefrom documentation: https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/sceneform/animation/

There is also a specific model animation sample supporting this and referred to be the documentation available: https://github.com/google-ar/sceneform-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/animation